# why negative bias is giving wrong result in this perceptron?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, perceptron

I'm studying Neural Network by the book Artificial Neural Networks: A Practical Course, i was building a neural network to the exercise of the book, the book said to me use bias equal to -1, i did it, but the result that i got was wrong for some inputs, i don't know why, but when i change the bias to 1 or other number positive i got the correct answer for all inputs, i thought that because is a number that will be update in each interaction with the weights this shouldn't happen, but is happening, i will be so grateful if someone help me or try help me, sorry for my bad English, this is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

from random import uniform

input_train = [[-0.6508, 0.1097, 4.0009], [-1.4492, 0.8896, 4.4005], [2.0850, 0.6876, 12.0710], [0.2626, 1.1476, 7.7985], [0.6418, 1.0234, 7.0427],
               [0.2569, 0.6730, 8.3265], [1.1155, 0.6043, 7.4446], [0.0914, 0.3399, 7.0677], [0.0121, 0.5256, 4.6316], [-0.0429, 0.4660, 5.4323],
               [0.4340, 0.6870, 8.2287], [0.2735, 1.0287, 7.1934], [0.4839, 0.4851, 7.4850], [0.4089, -0.1267, 5.5019], [1.4391, 0.1614, 8.5843],
               [-0.9115, -0.1973, 2.1962], [0.3654, 1.0475, 7.4858], [0.2144, 0.7515, 7.1699], [0.2013, 1.0014, 6.5489], [0.6483, 0.2183, 5.8991],
               [-0.1147, 0.2242, 7.2435], [-0.7970, 0.8795, 3.8762], [-1.0625, 0.6366, 2.4707], [0.5307, 0.1285, 5.6883], [-1.2200, 0.7777, 1.7252],
               [0.3957, 0.1076, 5.6623], [-0.1013, 0.5989, 7.1812], [2.4482, 0.9455, 11.2095], [2.0149, 0.6192, 10.9263], [0.2012,0.2611,5.4631]]

output_train = [-1.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000,
                -1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000,
                -1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000, -1.000,
                -1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000,
                -1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000,
                -1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000]

class perceptron:
    "Perceptron Implementation : Hebb Rule"

```
def __init__(self, data, output, epoch, bias, learning_rate = 0.01):
    self.data = data
    self.output = output
    self.epoch = epoch
    self.bias = bias
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.n_samples = len(data)
    self.n_atributtes = len(data[0])
    self.weights = self.GenWeights()

def train(self):
    for epoch in range(self.epoch):
        erro = False
        for row in range(self.n_samples):
            result = self.Predict(self.data[row])

            if result is not self.output[row]:
                self.bias = self.UpdateBias(result, self.output[row])
                for weights in range(self.n_atributtes):
                    self.weights[weights] = self.UpdateWeights(self.weights[weights], result, self.output[row], self.data[row][weights])
                erro = True

        if not erro: break

    return

def Predict(self, datarow):
    sum = self.bias
    for ele in range(self.n_atributtes):
        sum += datarow[ele] * self.weights[ele]
    return 1.0000 if sum >= 0.0 else -1.0000

def UpdateWeights(self, weight, predict, expected, inputc):
    return weight + (((expected - predict) * self.learning_rate) * inputc)

def UpdateBias(self, predict, expected):
    return self.bias + (((expected - predict) * self.learning_rate) * -1 )

def GenWeights(self):
    weights = list()
    for atributtes in range(self.n_atributtes):
        weights.insert(atributtes, uniform(0, 1))
    return weights

def NewEntry(self, newrow):
    sum = self.bias
    for ele in range(self.n_atributtes):
        sum += newrow[ele] * self.weights[ele]
    return 1.0000 if sum >= 0.0 else -1.0000
```

def main():

```
first_neural_network = perceptron(input_train, output_train, 1000, -1)
print("Initial Weights : {}" .format(first_neural_network.weights))
first_neural_network.train()
print("Trained Weights : {} and final bias : {} ".format(first_neural_network.weights, first_neural_network.bias))
a = 0
newlist = []
while True:
    a = float(input("Enter With the first number : "))
    newlist.append(a)
    a = float(input("Enter with the second number : "))
    newlist.append(a)
    a = float(input("Enter with the third number : "))
    newlist.append(a)
    print(newlist)
    print("result is : {0}", format(first_neural_network.NewEntry(newlist)))
    newlist.clear()


del first_neural_network
return
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

Answer (score 0):

modify your `main` function to fetch `error rate`

```
def main():
    first_neural_network = perceptron(input_train, output_train, 1000, 1)
    print("Initial Weights : {}" .format(first_neural_network.weights))
    first_neural_network.train()
    print("Trained Weights : {} and final bias : {} ".format(
        first_neural_network.weights, first_neural_network.bias))
    # a = 0
    # newlist = []
    # while True:
    #     a = float(input("Enter With the first number : "))
    #     newlist.append(a)
    #     a = float(input("Enter with the second number : "))
    #     newlist.append(a)
    #     a = float(input("Enter with the third number : "))
    #     newlist.append(a)
    #     print(newlist)
    #     print("result is : {0}".format(
    #         first_neural_network.NewEntry(newlist)))
    #     newlist.clear()
    nb_error = 0
    for newlist, expected in zip(input_train, output_train):
        pred = first_neural_network.NewEntry(newlist)
        print('true: {:2f} pred: {:2f}'.format(expected, pred))
        nb_error += pred != expected
    print('error rate%:{:.2f}'.format(float(nb_error)/first_neural_network.n_samples))

    del first_neural_network
    return
```

In your config, `error rate` is about 0.47. tune `bias` dont play a vital role in the metric.
I assume your data is NOT linearly separate, you need more complex model to boost accuracy